# Merging text of list items while keeping the same order using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have two arrays:

```
<ul id="titles">
  <li>title 1</li>
  <li>title 2</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul id="descs">
  <li>desc 1</li>
  <li>desc 2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for the result:

```
<ul id="titles">
  <li>title 1 <span>desc 1</span></li>
  <li>title 2 <span>desc 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

The code I'm using:

```
var li_D = $('#descs li').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
var li_T = $('#titles li').append(function(){
  return"<span>"+li_D+"</span>"
});
```

but it returns this result:

```
<ul id="titles">
  <li>title 1<span>desc 1,desc 2</span></li>
  <li>title 2<span>desc 1,desc 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/093k892a/)

How do I merge the list items from each ul to get each title with its description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to changing html of every li. In the callback of function get text of relevant element in `#descs` using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```js
$('#titles li').html(function(i, html) {
  return html + " <span>"+ $("#descs li").eq(i).text() +"</span>";
});
```

```css
#titles span {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="titles">
  <li>title 1</li>
  <li>title 2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="descs">
  <li>desc 1</li>
  <li>desc 2</li>
</ul>
```